# Нужно изменить данные в переменной при клике

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго времени суток, моя ситуация заключается в чем:

есть переменная `settings` и в ней есть настройка - `scrollWheel`, а в ней `enabled: true`

```
    var settings = {

    // Scroll wheel.
    scrollWheel: {

        // If true, enables scrolling via the scroll wheel.
        enabled: true,

        // Sets the scroll wheel factor. (Ideally) a value between 0 and 1 (lower = slower scroll, higher = faster scroll).
        factor: 1

    },
}
```

мне нужно чтобы `enabled: true`, при клике на блок с `id="card"` менялся на `enabled: false`. Надеюсь на вашу помощь, и заранее благодарен.

```
(function($) {

// Settings.
var settings = {

    // Keyboard shortcuts.
    keyboardShortcuts: {

        // If true, enables scrolling via keyboard shortcuts.
        enabled: true,

        // Sets the distance to scroll when using the left/right arrow keys.
        distance: 50

    },

    // Scroll wheel.
    scrollWheel: {

        // If true, enables scrolling via the scroll wheel.
        enabled: true,

        // Sets the scroll wheel factor. (Ideally) a value between 0 and 1 (lower = slower scroll, higher = faster scroll).
        factor: 1

    },

    // Scroll zones.
    scrollZones: {

        // If true, enables scrolling via scroll zones on the left/right edges of the scren.
        enabled: true,

        // Sets the speed at which the page scrolls when a scroll zone is active (higher = faster scroll, lower = slower scroll).
        speed: 15

    },

    // Dragging.
    dragging: {

        // If true, enables scrolling by dragging the main wrapper with the mouse.
        enabled: true,

        // Sets the momentum factor. Must be a value between 0 and 1 (lower = less momentum, higher = more momentum, 0 = disable momentum scrolling).
        momentum: 0.875,

        // Sets the drag threshold (in pixels).
        threshold: 10

    },

    // If set to a valid selector , prevents key/mouse events from bubbling from these elements.
    excludeSelector: 'input:focus, select:focus, textarea:focus, audio, video, iframe',

    // Link scroll speed.
    linkScrollSpeed: 1000

};

// Skel.
skel.breakpoints({
    xlarge: '(max-width: 1680px)',
    large: '(max-width: 1280px)',
    medium: '(max-width: 980px)',
    small: '(max-width: 780px)',
    xsmall: '(max-width: 480px)',
    xxsmall: '(max-width: 360px)',
    short: '(min-aspect-ratio: 16/7)',
    xshort: '(min-aspect-ratio: 16/6)'
});

// Ready event.
$(function() {

    // Vars.
    var $window = $(window),
            $document = $(document),
            $body = $('body'),
            $html = $('html'),
            $bodyHtml = $('body,html'),
            $wrapper = $('#js-content-wrapper');

    // Disable animations/transitions until the page has loaded.
    $body.addClass('is-loading');

    $window.on('load', function() {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            $body.removeClass('is-loading');
        }, 100);
    });

    // Tweaks/fixes.

    // Mobile: Revert to native scrolling.
    if (skel.vars.mobile) {

        // Disable all scroll-assist features.
        settings.keyboardShortcuts.enabled = false;
        settings.scrollWheel.enabled = false;
        settings.scrollZones.enabled = false;
        settings.dragging.enabled = false;

        // Re-enable overflow on body.
        $body.css('overflow-x', 'auto');

    }

    // IE: Various fixes.
    if (skel.vars.browser == 'ie') {

        // Enable IE mode.
        $body.addClass('is-ie');

        // Page widths.
        $window
            .on('load resize', function() {

            // Calculate wrapper width.
            var w = 0;

            $wrapper.children().each(function() {
                w += $(this).width();
            });

            // Apply to page.
            $html.css('width', w + 'px');

        });

    }

    // Polyfill: Object fit.
    if (!skel.canUse('object-fit')) {

        $('.image[data-position]').each(function() {

            var $this = $(this),
                    $img = $this.children('img');

            // Apply img as background.
            $this
                .css('background-image', 'url("' + $img.attr('src') + '")')
                .css('background-position', $this.data('position'))
                .css('background-size', 'cover')
                .css('background-repeat', 'no-repeat');

            // Hide img.
            $img
                .css('opacity', '0');

        });

    }

    // Keyboard shortcuts.
    if (settings.keyboardShortcuts.enabled)
        (function() {

            $wrapper

            // Prevent keystrokes inside excluded elements from bubbling.
                .on('keypress keyup keydown', settings.excludeSelector, function(event) {

                // Stop propagation.
                event.stopPropagation();

            });

            $window

            // Keypress event.
                .on('keydown', function(event) {

                var scrolled = false;

                switch (event.keyCode) {

                        // Left arrow.
                    case 37:
                        $document.scrollLeft($document.scrollLeft() - settings.keyboardShortcuts.distance);
                        scrolled = true;
                        break;

                        // Right arrow.
                    case 39:
                        $document.scrollLeft($document.scrollLeft() + settings.keyboardShortcuts.distance);
                        scrolled = true;
                        break;

                        // Page Up.
                    case 33:
                        $document.scrollLeft($document.scrollLeft() - $window.width() + 100);
                        scrolled = true;
                        break;

                        // Page Down, Space.
                    case 34:
                    case 32:
                        $document.scrollLeft($document.scrollLeft() + $window.width() - 100);
                        scrolled = true;
                        break;

                        // Home.
                    case 36:
                        $document.scrollLeft(0);
                        scrolled = true;
                        break;

                        // End.
                    case 35:
                        $document.scrollLeft($document.width());
                        scrolled = true;
                        break;

                                                         }

                // Scrolled?
                if (scrolled) {

                    // Prevent default.
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();

                    // Stop link scroll.
                    $bodyHtml.stop();

                }

            });

        })();

    // Scroll wheel.
    if (settings.scrollWheel.enabled)
        (function() {

            // Based on code by @miorel + @pieterv of Facebook (thanks guys :)
            // github.com/facebook/fixed-data-table/blob/master/src/vendor_upstream/dom/normalizeWheel.js
            var normalizeWheel = function(event) {

                var pixelStep = 10,
                        lineHeight = 40,
                        pageHeight = 800,
                        sX = 0,
                        sY = 0,
                        pX = 0,
                        pY = 0;

                // Legacy.
                if ('detail' in event)
                    sY = event.detail;
                else if ('wheelDelta' in event)
                    sY = event.wheelDelta / -120;
                else if ('wheelDeltaY' in event)
                    sY = event.wheelDeltaY / -120;

                if ('wheelDeltaX' in event)
                    sX = event.wheelDeltaX / -120;

                // Side scrolling on FF with DOMMouseScroll.
                if ('axis' in event
                        &&  event.axis === event.HORIZONTAL_AXIS) {
                    sX = sY;
                    sY = 0;
                }

                // Calculate.
                pX = sX * pixelStep;
                pY = sY * pixelStep;

                if ('deltaY' in event)
                    pY = event.deltaY;

                if ('deltaX' in event)
                    pX = event.deltaX;

                if ((pX || pY)
                        &&  event.deltaMode) {

                    if (event.deltaMode == 1) {
                        pX *= lineHeight;
                        pY *= lineHeight;
                    }
                    else {
                        pX *= pageHeight;
                        pY *= pageHeight;
                    }

                }

                // Fallback if spin cannot be determined.
                if (pX && !sX)
                    sX = (pX < 1) ? -1 : 1;

                if (pY && !sY)
                    sY = (pY < 1) ? -1 : 1;

                // Return.
                return {
                    spinX: sX,
                    spinY: sY,
                    pixelX: pX,
                    pixelY: pY
                };

            };

            // Wheel event.
            $body.on('wheel', function(event) {

                // Disable on <=small.
                if (skel.breakpoint('small').active)
                    return;

                // Prevent default.
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();

                // Stop link scroll.
                $bodyHtml.stop();

                // Calculate delta, direction.
                var n = normalizeWheel(event.originalEvent),
                        x = (n.pixelX != 0 ? n.pixelX : n.pixelY),
                        delta = Math.min(Math.abs(x), 150) * settings.scrollWheel.factor,
                        direction = x > 0 ? 1 : -1;

                // Scroll page.
                $document.scrollLeft($document.scrollLeft() + (delta * direction));

            });

        })();

    // Scroll zones.
    if (settings.scrollZones.enabled)
        (function() {

            var $left = $('<div class="scrollZone left"></div>'),
                    $right = $('<div class="scrollZone right"></div>'),
                    $zones = $left.add($right),
                    paused = false,
                    intervalId = null,
                    direction,
                    activate = function(d) {

                        // Disable on <=small.
                        if (skel.breakpoint('small').active)
                            return;

                        // Paused? Bail.
                        if (paused)
                            return;

                        // Stop link scroll.
                        $bodyHtml.stop();

                        // Set direction.
                        direction = d;

                        // Initialize interval.
                        clearInterval(intervalId);

                        intervalId = setInterval(function() {
                            $document.scrollLeft($document.scrollLeft() + (settings.scrollZones.speed * direction));
                        }, 25);

                    },
                    deactivate = function() {

                        // Unpause.
                        paused = false;

                        // Clear interval.
                        clearInterval(intervalId);

                    };

            $zones
                .appendTo($wrapper)
                .on('mouseleave mousedown', function(event) {
                deactivate();
            });

            $left
                .css('left', '0')
                .on('mouseenter', function(event) {
                activate(-1);
            });

            $right
                .css('right', '0')
                .on('mouseenter', function(event) {
                activate(1);
            });

            $wrapper
                .on('---pauseScrollZone', function(event) {

                // Pause.
                paused = true;

                // Unpause after delay.
                setTimeout(function() {
                    paused = false;
                }, 500);

            });

        })();

    // Dragging.
    if (settings.dragging.enabled)
        (function() {

            var dragging = false,
                    dragged = false,
                    distance = 0,
                    startScroll,
                    momentumIntervalId, velocityIntervalId,
                    startX, currentX, previousX,
                    velocity, direction;

            $wrapper

            // Prevent image drag and drop.
                .on('mouseup mousemove mousedown', '.image, img', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
            })

            // Prevent mouse events inside excluded elements from bubbling.
                .on('mouseup mousemove mousedown', settings.excludeSelector, function(event) {

                // Prevent event from bubbling.
                event.stopPropagation();

                // End drag.
                dragging = false;
                $wrapper.removeClass('is-dragging');
                clearInterval(velocityIntervalId);
                clearInterval(momentumIntervalId);

                // Pause scroll zone.
                $wrapper.triggerHandler('---pauseScrollZone');

            })

            // Mousedown event.
                .on('mousedown', function(event) {

                // Disable on <=small.
                if (skel.breakpoint('small').active)
                    return;

                // Clear momentum interval.
                clearInterval(momentumIntervalId);

                // Stop link scroll.
                $bodyHtml.stop();

                // Start drag.
                dragging = true;
                $wrapper.addClass('is-dragging');

                // Initialize and reset vars.
                startScroll = $document.scrollLeft();
                startX = event.clientX;
                previousX = startX;
                currentX = startX;
                distance = 0;
                direction = 0;

                // Initialize velocity interval.
                clearInterval(velocityIntervalId);

                velocityIntervalId = setInterval(function() {

                    // Calculate velocity, direction.
                    velocity = Math.abs(currentX - previousX);
                    direction = (currentX > previousX ? -1 : 1);

                    // Update previous X.
                    previousX = currentX;

                }, 50);

            })

            // Mousemove event.
                .on('mousemove', function(event) {

                // Not dragging? Bail.
                if (!dragging)
                    return;

                // Velocity.
                currentX = event.clientX;

                // Scroll page.
                $document.scrollLeft(startScroll + (startX - currentX));

                // Update distance.
                distance = Math.abs(startScroll - $document.scrollLeft());

                // Distance exceeds threshold? Disable pointer events on all descendents.
                if (!dragged
                        &&  distance > settings.dragging.threshold) {

                    $wrapper.addClass('is-dragged');

                    dragged = true;

                }

            })

            // Mouseup/mouseleave event.
                .on('mouseup mouseleave', function(event) {

                var m;

                // Not dragging? Bail.
                if (!dragging)
                    return;

                // Dragged? Re-enable pointer events on all descendents.
                if (dragged) {

                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $wrapper.removeClass('is-dragged');
                    }, 100);

                    dragged = false;

                }

                // Distance exceeds threshold? Prevent default.
                if (distance > settings.dragging.threshold)
                    event.preventDefault();

                // End drag.
                dragging = false;
                $wrapper.removeClass('is-dragging');
                clearInterval(velocityIntervalId);
                clearInterval(momentumIntervalId);

                // Pause scroll zone.
                $wrapper.triggerHandler('---pauseScrollZone');

                // Initialize momentum interval.
                if (settings.dragging.momentum > 0) {

                    m = velocity;

                    momentumIntervalId = setInterval(function() {

                        // Scroll page.
                        $document.scrollLeft($document.scrollLeft() + (m * direction));

                        // Decrease momentum.
                        m = m * settings.dragging.momentum;

                        // Negligible momentum? Clear interval and end.
                        if (Math.abs(m) < 1)
                            clearInterval(momentumIntervalId);

                    }, 15);

                }

            });

        })();

    // Link scroll.
    $wrapper
        .on('mousedown mouseup', 'a[href^="#"]', function(event) {

        // Stop propagation.
        event.stopPropagation();

    })
        .on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function(event) {

        var $this = $(this),
                href = $this.attr('href'),
                $target, x, y;

        // Get target.
        if (href == '#'
                ||  ($target = $(href)).length == 0)
            return;

        // Prevent default.
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        // Calculate x, y.
        if (skel.breakpoint('small').active) {

            x = $target.offset().top - (Math.max(0, $window.height() - $target.outerHeight()) / 2);
            y = { scrollTop: x };

        }
        else {

            x = $target.offset().left - (Math.max(0, $window.width() - $target.outerWidth()) / 2);
            y = { scrollLeft: x };

        }

        // Scroll.
        $bodyHtml
            .stop()
            .animate(
            y,
            settings.linkScrollSpeed,
            'swing'
        );

    });

    // Gallery.
    $('.gallery')
        .on('click', 'a', function(event) {

        var $a = $(this),
                $gallery = $a.parents('.gallery'),
                $modal = $gallery.children('.modal'),
                $modalImg = $modal.find('img'),
                href = $a.attr('href');

        // Not an image? Bail.
        if (!href.match(/\.(jpg|gif|png|mp4)$/))
            return;

        // Prevent default.
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        // Locked? Bail.
        if ($modal[0]._locked)
            return;

        // Lock.
        $modal[0]._locked = true;

        // Set src.
        $modalImg.attr('src', href);

        // Set visible.
        $modal.addClass('visible');

        // Focus.
        $modal.focus();

        // Delay.
        setTimeout(function() {

            // Unlock.
            $modal[0]._locked = false;

        }, 600);

    })
        .on('click', '.modal', function(event) {

        var $modal = $(this),
                $modalImg = $modal.find('img');

        // Locked? Bail.
        if ($modal[0]._locked)
            return;

        // Already hidden? Bail.
        if (!$modal.hasClass('visible'))
            return;

        // Stop propagation.
        event.stopPropagation();

        // Lock.
        $modal[0]._locked = true;

        // Clear visible, loaded.
        $modal
            .removeClass('loaded')

        // Delay.
        setTimeout(function() {

            $modal
                .removeClass('visible')

            // Pause scroll zone.
            $wrapper.triggerHandler('---pauseScrollZone');

            setTimeout(function() {

                // Clear src.
                $modalImg.attr('src', '');

                // Unlock.
                $modal[0]._locked = false;

                // Focus.
                $body.focus();

            }, 475);

        }, 125);

    })
        .on('keypress', '.modal', function(event) {

        var $modal = $(this);

        // Escape? Hide modal.
        if (event.keyCode == 27)
            $modal.trigger('click');

    })
        .on('mouseup mousedown mousemove', '.modal', function(event) {

        // Stop propagation.
        event.stopPropagation();

    })
        .prepend('<div class="modal" tabIndex="-1"><div class="inner"><img src="" /></div></div>')
        .find('img')
        .on('load', function(event) {

        var $modalImg = $(this),
                $modal = $modalImg.parents('.modal');

        setTimeout(function() {

            // No longer visible? Bail.
            if (!$modal.hasClass('visible'))
                return;

            // Set loaded.
            $modal.addClass('loaded');

        }, 275);

    });

});

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: `$("#card").click(function(){ settings.scrollWheel.enabled = !settings.scrollWheel.enabled; });`

Comment: @Igor, не работает :(

Comment: работает, Вы неправильно скопировали к себе мой код

Comment: а куда мне вставлять Ваш код? после функции или куда?

Comment: Вы шутите? Откуда я знаю, куда Вам вставлять код? Добавьте достаточно информации/разметки/скрипта в вопрос, чтобы получился пример воспроизводящий Вашу ситуацию - тогда посмотрим.

Comment: @Igor простите пожалуйста, добавил код.

Comment: вставьте мой код перед строчкой `var settings = {`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68410/discussion-between---and-igor).